# Animation is complete, what now?

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm new to Blender and so I followed a tutorial on how to animate a map. It's really a great tutorial especially for beginners. However, the tutorial does not include what to do after all the elements of the animation are complete. I can playback the animation in the material viewport shading, but when I do playback in rendered viewport shading it's very blurry.

So what do I do next to create a "movie" of this animation? I imagine the full animation has to be rendered first. I hit the animation button under the render section and it looked like Blender rendered every frame of the animation, but I don't know what to do next. I don't know what happened to all of those rendered frames. Can someone please help?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: choose your render engine, check your lightings, select your render frame range, select your output path, always use image as your output format, never use videos like avi, click animate. Then you'll get a folder full of image sequence. Then blender's job is done from this point.

Comment: To find the rendered frames you already did, look at the Output panel in the Render settings for the path and file name of the rendered images. To compile them all into a single movie file (if they aren't), you need to load them into the sequence editor and compile them from there. Please read the Blender docs on how to do this. Not the best source of information, but the first you should look at.

Comment: Guys/gals....thank you so much! I will look up the output folder and see if the images are there. I believe the default setting was to output to PNG files. I just hope the files are where they're supposed to be.

Comment: Hello all, I was able to look up the output directory and found the rendered frames just as you all suggested. Was able to create a mini movie out of those frames. Thanks again to you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to select the [output format](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html#output-panel), if you select image file format (PNG, JPG,...) every frame of the animation will be saved as single image, on the other side if you select video format (H.264,...) animation will be saved as video. The destination of the saved video or frame images is specified by the [output path](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html#output-panel).

It is recommended to render the animation as images and then make video using the Video Sequencer, because if something happens halfway rendering the animation you can start it again from the last rendered frame, which is not possible when the output format is video.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I will check the output folder for the PNG files.

Comment: http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/render-to-pngs.html has some examples of using ffmpeg to encode stills into a movie.  There are many other examples on the internet.

Comment: @ Stefan Schindler, I was able to look up the output directory and found the rendered frames just as you suggested. Was able to create a mini movie out of those frames. Thanks again!